# Adjust factors in dataset with dynamic preceding zero's

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a big `data.frame` (1.9M records, with 20 columns). One of the columns is a factor column with values of digits with different length (different number of characters/digits, e.g. 567839, 234324324, 3243211 etc.)
Note: these are numeric codes, no real values, could also be just characters of different lengths for this example.

Now I want to convert does factors to become 13-digit-factors, in such a way that a factor gets preceding zero's in case the number of digits is less than 13.

Example:

```
Old factor      Length  New factor
432543532532    12      0432543532532
3285087250932   13      3285087250932
464577534       9       0000464577534
2225324324324   13      2225324324324
864235325264    12      0864235325264
```

I tried different approaches, but now I'm stuck. The problem is that the lengte of the factor differs throughout the dataset.

I tried the following, with an example.

Create `data.frame` with three different columns on which I perform my code, to identify the problem.

```
> df.test <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("432543532532", "3285087250932", "464577534", "2225324324324", "864235325264"), c("3285087250932", "132543532532", "464577534", "2225324324324", "864235325264"), c("164577534", "3285087250932", "432543532532", "2225324324324", "864235325264")))
> df.test
             V1            V2            V3
1  432543532532 3285087250932     164577534
2 3285087250932  132543532532 3285087250932
3     464577534     464577534  432543532532
4 2225324324324 2225324324324 2225324324324
5  864235325264  864235325264  864235325264

> levels(df.test$V1) <- paste(substr("0000000000000", 0, 13 - nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V1)))), levels(df.test$V1), sep = '')
> levels(df.test$V2) <- paste(substr("0000000000000", 0, 13 - nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V2)))), levels(df.test$V2), sep = '')
> levels(df.test$V3) <- paste(substr("0000000000000", 0, 13 - nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V3)))), levels(df.test$V3), sep = '')
> df.test
             V1             V2                V3
1  432543532532 03285087250932     0000164577534
2 3285087250932  0132543532532 00003285087250932
3     464577534     0464577534  0000432543532532
4 2225324324324 02225324324324 00002225324324324
5  864235325264  0864235325264  0000864235325264
```

The problem is that the code `nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V1)))` not uses the lengths of the vector `df.test$V1` but just one value; the length of the first level of the factor (which is on alphabet/ascending). And it performs the number of necessary preceding zeros on all records. So no vector code!

Note: if I run the 'nchar' code seperately it gives me a vector of the lengths of all the records as a result, so I assumed it should work...

```
> nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V1)))
[1] 13 13 12  9 12
> nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V2)))
[1] 13 14 14 10 13
> nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V3)))
[1] 13 17 17 16 16
```

Why isn't `nchar(as.character(levels(df.test$V1)))` running as a vector operator?
Can anybody tell me how to change my code, so it will have the correct result?

Thanks in advance!

NB. Note that in the real case I only need to perform this adjustment on onecolumn of the `data.frame`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for zero padding you can use `sprintf('%04d', 1:5)` but the codes in your example need to be numeric.

```
max.nchar <- max(nchar(levels(df.test$V1)))

sprintf(paste0('%0',max.nchar), as.numeric(levels(df$V1))[df$V1])
```

Maybe there is a better way... but you can use `gsub` with `sprintf`:

```
gsub(' ', '0', sprintf('%04s', levels(factor(10:15))))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `sprintf('%013s',as.character(df.test$V1))` on the characters directly? With that many digits you may run into trouble with the accuracy of the conversion to integers or numeric.

Comment: @joran Thats a good point and certainly worth considering.  However, `'%s' "pads" with spaces instead of zeros.  For that method you could use the bottom example since levels of factors are treated as character strings. Then `gsub` the spaces to `'0'`.

Comment: Are you sure? `sprintf('%05s',as.character(1:5))` pads with 0's for me just fine.

Comment: yeah, pads with spaces.  I thought it was because I have `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in my profile, but I turned it off and still the same behavior...

Comment: Weird. Maybe a change between 2.14.2 and 2.15.0? I don't see anything in the change notes, but you never know...

Comment: I'm on 2.15.0 from the Ubuntu package... but that is odd.

Comment: I used the `gsub` variant. Worked perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
as.data.frame( lapply(df.test, sprintf, fmt="%013s"))
#---------------------    
         V1            V2            V3
1 0432543532532 3285087250932 0000164577534
2 3285087250932 0132543532532 3285087250932
3 0000464577534 0000464577534 0432543532532
4 2225324324324 2225324324324 2225324324324
5 0864235325264 0864235325264 0864235325264
```

Comment: Finally! Someone else running 2.14.2? Which platform? (We just had a conversation about this in the R chat room.)

Comment: Yeah.  2.14.2. I'm also still on OSX 10.5.8.

Comment: This method didn't work for me...only white spaces, no zero's. Probably something to do with the version? I'm running 2.14.2 btw, on Windows 7.

Comment: @FBE Yes, there was an extended discussion about this in the R chatroom earlier. It appears that the behavior on OSX is different, but it's unclear (to me) as to why, and which output is "correct" and which is a bug. I'm investigating with some higher authorities.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working because `substr` return "a character vector of the same length and with the same attributes as `x` (after possible coercion)". So you have to make sure `x` has as many elements as your expected return value

```
df.test <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("432543532532", "3285087250932", "464577534", "2225324324324", "864235325264"), c("3285087250932", "132543532532", "464577534", "2225324324324", "864235325264"), c("164577534", "3285087250932", "432543532532", "2225324324324", "864235325264")))
df.test

n <- nrow(df.test)
start <- rep(0, n)
padStrs <- rep("0000000000000", n)
for (thevar in colnames(df.test))) {
    cdiff1 <- 13 - nchar(as.character(levels(df.test[, thevar])))
    levels(df.test[, thevar]) <- paste(substr(padStrs, 0, cdiff), levels(df.test[, thevar]), sep = '')
}
```